# command-click git commit ID in Terminal, and be taken to that commit in github?

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, git, github

I'm running a Mac and use iTerm with ZSH as my shell.

Currently I can command-click (⌘+click) on links or directories in my iTerm window, and that directory or web link will open.

Is there a way (plugin, config tweak, etc) to make it so I can do a `git log`, and then command-click on a git commit ID, and be taken directly to that commit on Github? This would make my life much easier. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no(t practically).  There's no way to know if a given hash is even a Git commit ID, and if it is, whether it's on GitHub, a local git repo, or any of the hozillion other git repository hosting sites out there.